# paypal 10486 no "Buyer's Experience" on redirect

Tags: php, error-handling, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the paypal sandbox to test my payment flow.

I'm trying to react to the error messages that paypal returns. In this case error 10486: "This transaction couldn't be completed. Please redirect your customer to PayPal."

[edit] On my webpage I show the error and the user has a link to redirect to paypal again. [/edit]

I redirect the user to paypal like described in this
[document](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/).

```
if(isset($_GET['token'])){
   $token = $_GET['token']
   $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
   header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
   header('Location: ' . $url);
}
```

I´m using the same token.
Everything fine, but the user gets no message about what went wrong and why he has been redirected to paypal.

Does anybody know if I did something wrong or if there is something to change in the account settings for showing the error in the sandbox or maybe the sandbox is buggy and doesn't show the error message.

Comment: you should (nearly) always put an exit() after the header('Location:')... just because the browser is redirected, does not mean the rest of the PHP isn't processed... also, anything in $_GET has been de-urlencoded for you... so when you include it in a url, you need to urlencode() the value again (just incase the 'token' variable was to contain a character such as "&").

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" immediately when the customer returns to the website (so the customer does not have to confirm for the 3rd time, at a point when they assume the payment has been made)?

If so, I think PayPal is checking the browsers Referrer header... where if you don't show a page to the user, the browsers Referrer header will still be set to paypal.com, and this seems to suppress the showing of the error message.

The solution I've found so far is to show an error page on your website, with a link (not redirect) back to the PayPal website... which as you can tell, is not great, and I think is more of a bug on PayPals side (so the usual then).

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I found out, that this only happens in the Sandbox. When I try it in the Live website, everything works fine.

Comment: Ahh, thanks... I must admit I was only checking in Sandbox as I didn't want to upload that to Live (and is another case of the Sandbox being completely different to Live).

Comment: I'm sorry, I write in my Question, that I make a redirect. Yes I make a redirect, but with a link on an error page on my webpage. I have updated this in my Question.

Comment: ok, I think the same applies... but as long as its "fixed" for live, then I don't think there is much else we can do (I have raised the error with PayPal, but as always, no response).

Comment: I bit late to the party but this is still the case. If you direct back to paypal without displaying a page between, the error message is not shown and the user would just be in a permanent loop of a payment failing with no reason given.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry you're having problems. According to the PayPal community, this code indicates your card was declined by your bank; so your first course should be to get in touch with the card issuer. If that does not resolve, it's a simple matter to phone PayPal customer support, and here's the quickest way. Instead of phoning PayPal's 800 support number, go to this special page after logging in:
www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/helpscr?cmd=_contact-phone
To shortcut the seemingly interminable phone menu, repeat "Agent" in response to every prompt.

Comment: This doesn't answer this question at all ... I'm having same trouble with this 10486 BS. The documentation is not "complete" at all and none of the answers I've found on SO match with today's "profile" ui